# php mysql brute force protection with ip address

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, ip, brute-force

I have a problem. I have programmed a brute force protection for my web login [php, mysql] .The failed-attempts will be saved in the database with the ip address.

My problem:
I have try my login in my school, and detected that all computers in my school have the same IP-address. That means that if one student will be blocked, my login doesn't work in the whole school.

How can I fix this bug?

Thanks alot for your answers.

best regards Freddy C.

Comment: You can't, in general.

Comment: Is not there anyway to lock only the computer?

Comment: Can you get the machine MAC address, HD serial or external IP?

Comment: I don't know how to get these addresses in PHP, so far I've never needed them.

Comment: @PiLHA All you can usually get is external IP. MAC address and other similar details don't normally make it to the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a bug. It is the nature of typical shared internet connections. This provides two big benefits:

1. Conserve the limited availability of IPv4 addresses.
2. Protect systems from open port attacks. If a port is open on an individual system directly connected to the internet then it is vulnerable to attacks on that port. If the system is on a shared internet connection with the router using a single public IP address then the router will block data on most ports from getting to any system and if they are necessary (e.g., SSH into one system) then only one system is vulnerable for each port instead of every system.

The problem, as you have found, is that outside systems can't easily distinguish between systems on the other side of the router. This often causes problems if one system is infected with a spam/virus bot - realtime blacklists (RBLs) will block the IP address of the entire local network and in a large organization it may be hard to track down the offending system in order to fix the problem.

For more basic "block the bad guys from my server", you can use:

- List item
- a high threshold (e.g., 100 failed attempts instead of 3)
- base the block on a specific window (e.g., I have one system where I automatically block by IP address based on 5 failed transactions in one day and reset the count every day)
- base the block on a combination of username (or other key credentials) + IP address - which will work well for someone trying to hack into a single account but won't help if they are trying "random account + likely password".
- block IP addresses only after checking the geographic location - e.g., if your users are all normally in the USA and you see an occasional logins from elsewhere (regular users traveling) then you may be able to block all non-USA logins after a shorter number of attempts than you would block USA logins.